# Entity Resolution of customers using email and phone

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a customers table with id, full_name, email, and phone

```
| id | full_name      | email                      | phone         |
| -- | -------------- | -------------------------- | ------------- |
| 1  | namita.robin   | nr2035@gmail.com           | +135698887445 |
| 2  | alfred.buka    | rim_alfred@yahoo.com       | +236588547811 |
| 3  | karim.tazi     | kr_tzi@krtzi.ma            | +212661845794 |
| 4  |                | robinrobin@gmail.com       | +135698887445 |
| 5  | cheri          | robinrobin@gmail.com       | +135698748788 |
| 6  | rim.rim        | rim_alfred@yahoo.com       | +245881148787 |
```

and I want to group customers that have at least an email or phone that is the same.
desired output for this example would be:

```
| id | full_name      | email                      | phone         | master_id |
| -- | -------------- | -------------------------- | ------------- | --------- |
| 1  | namita.robin   | nr2035@gmail.com           | +135698887445 | 1         |
| 2  | alfred.buka    | rim_alfred@yahoo.com       | +236588547811 | 2         |
| 3  | karim.tazi     | kr_tzi@krtzi.ma            | +212661845794 | 3         |
| 4  |                | robinrobin@gmail.com       | +135698887445 | 1         |
| 5  | cheri          | robinrobin@gmail.com       | +135698748788 | 1         |
| 6  | rim.rim        | rim_alfred@yahoo.com       | +245881148787 | 2         |
```

Comment: What if an Id shares both an email and phone with 2 other rows?

Comment: A partitioned `MIN`?

Comment: If person#1 has email abc & phone 123 and person#2 has email xyz & phone 123 then they are 'connected'.  If in turn person#3 has email xyz & phone 789, then #3 is connected to #2, which associatively means that #1 and #3 are also connected though they have nothing in common.  Treat this like a network connection problem not a simple grouping problem.

Comment: Yes, I would like to have a network thing going on, but all records should have 1 master row

Answer (score 0):

You can use dense_rank() to get the same id value for the same email type. Get only email type from the email column and order by that.

```
select * ,dense_rank() over(order by reverse(Substring(reverse(email),1,Charindex('@', reverse(email))-1)) ) as master_id
from customers 
order by reverse(Substring(reverse(email),1,Charindex('@', reverse(email))-1))
```

[image]